# Encryption/Decryption Python GCM

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, aes-gcm, pycryptodome

I am trying to decrypt a message sent by an app.  It uses AES-256 GCM.  It sends a JSON in like the following:

> ```
> text = {"content":"0WKFZaesPEP+nlNqcgiLDMapSsEp","iv":"c46c5cb0f1d016ac225ee82b","tag":"54f77d985b7844030d997508e8b9bcd1"}
> ```

Then I am trying to decrypt the data in Python using pycryptodome using AES-256 GCM.  I have the following code:

```
def decrypt(encryptedMsg, secretKey):
        authTag = encryptedMsg['tag']
        nonce = encryptedMsg['iv']
        ciphertext = encryptedMsg['content']
        secretKey = base64.b64decode(secretKey)
        aesCipher = AES.new(secretKey, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce.encode())
        plaintext = aesCipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext.encode(), authTag.encode())
        return (plaintext)
```

I think this is close to working.  Please note the secretKey is in base64 so it has to be decoded from base64 to be 32 characters. I am getting an error from this as follows:

```
raise ValueError("MAC check failed")
ValueError: MAC check failed
```

I have also tried using "decrypt" rather than "decrypt_and_verify" without the tag and I get an output but it does not make sense to me:

```
b'}A\xc2\x9c\xdd\xffk\x87\xa0\xa2\xd3\xa0\x8dB\x0f\xde\xb0h)n.\xea\x82C\x9f[s\\'
```

Comment: *MAC check failed* as well as meaningless data after decryption without authentication usually indicates inconsistent data (wrong key/IV/tag, corrupted ciphertext etc.). It looks like you are not decoding ciphertext, IV and tag correctly. The ciphertext seemst to be Base64 encoded, IV and Tag hex encoded. So you've to decode the data accordingly.

Comment: bytes.fromhex for IV and Tag and base64.b64decode for the ciphertext worked for me.  Thank you so much!